# How to add System.Collections.Generic 3.5 to Asp.net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm adding functionality to my existing Asp.net 2.0 application. I want to use some of the .net 3.5 features so I add some .net 3.5 assemblies to my web config. Which I added System.Core and System.Xml.Linq.

I want to use IEnumerable version 3.5, what library should I need to add to the web config?

Comment: There is no version 3.5 of `IEnumerable` (nor of `IEnumerable<T>`, for that matter).  What code are you trying to write, and what obstacles are you facing?

Comment: I'm basically doing this "msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137(v=vs.90).aspx". .net 2.0 missing the SequenceEqual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the reference assemblies like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation>
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you, work fine! After I added the <system.codedom> targeting v3.5!

Comment: Thanks.  I was not sure if that part was needed.  I originally added it, but took it out, so I guess it was needed after all.

Answer (score 0):

Since, in your comment, you mention that you're trying to use SequenceEqual, your problem is one of using the `System.Linq.Eumerable` class.  This class defines most, if not all, of Linq to Objects, as a large set of extension methods on the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` types.

The class is defined in the System.Core.dll assembly (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx for reference).

You say you've already added a System.Core reference, so I suppose you may not have added `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Also, extension methods were not yet added to C# in version 2.0, so if you're using the 2.0 compiler, you'll have to call the method as a static method.  Instead of

```
sequenceA.SequenceEqual(sequenceB)
```

you'll have to use

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(sequenceA, sequenceB)
```

Comment: I get this error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Eumerable, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @HardCode There is no System.Linq.Enumerable file; System.Linq.Enumerable is a class that's defined in System.Core.dll.

Comment: I added this in my web config: <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>. Do I need to add the dll as well?

Comment: Gives me error on Enumerable:  CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @HardCode No, the assembly reference *is* a reference to the dll; the dll *is* the assembly.  The "dll" part is implicit.  As to the type arguments, it depends on the types of the two sequences.  In the example you gave, the types are the same, so the error doesn't make sense.

Comment: Looks like it's using 2.0 compiler instead of 3.5. Resolved the issue based on Dana's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install .net 3.5 SP1 on the machine you're running on, you need to use at least Visual Studio 2008, and you need to go into your project properties and set the target Framework to 3.5.

If you're still using Visual Studio 2005, there may be tricks to invoke the compiler from .net 3.5, but it's not really pretty and well supported.

Also, make sure that you have a `using System.Linq;` statement in your .cs file, or the equivalent in your .aspx file if you're using inline-script blocks. `SequenceEquals` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to the IEnumerable class.

Comment: I'm not running the solution. I just edit the file, since it's not a application I don't need to compile.